# Java coding Markov Matrix

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, methods

Good Day!

I'm having issues with my current code. I'm trying to write a method with the header
public static boolean isMarkovMatrix(double[][] m)
that's supposed to check whether a matrix is a positive markov matrix.
Then in the main method I'm trying to prompt the user to enter a 3-by-3 matrix of double values, then test whether the inputted matrix is in fact a positive markov matrix.
to be more clear -a positive Markov matrix is a matrix where each element is positive and the sum of the elements in each column is 1.

Here's my current code, no matter what I input it continues to tell me that it's NOT a positive M.M when I know it is,
I'm still pretty new to coding, only taken two courses so far so I don't know anything too advanced fyi, thanks! hope someone can help...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);
    double[][] matrix = new double [3][3];
    
    System.out.println("Enter a 3-by-3 matrix row by row: ");
    for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++){
        for(int column = 0; column < 3; column++){
           matrix[row][column] = kbd.nextDouble();
        }
        kbd.nextLine();
    }
   //output 
   if(isMarkovMatrix(matrix)){
        System.out.println("It is a Markov Matrix.");
    } else if (!isMarkovMatrix(matrix)){
        System.out.println("It is not a Markov Matrix");
    }
}


public static boolean isMarkovMatrix(double[][] m){
    double sum;
    boolean answer = true;
    
    for(int row = 0; row < m.length; row++){
        sum = 0;
        for(int column = 0; column < m.length; column++){
            sum += m[row][column];
            if (sum != 1 || m[row][column] < 0){
                answer = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: What are your expected inputs and otputs?

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is checking the sum of a ROW, not a column. Additionally, you need to check if the sum is 1, AFTER exiting the nested for loop; otherwise you'll determine that it is "not" a valid matrix before you've had a chance to add up all the numbers.

So you need to swap the order of your rows/columns in the for loops, and move the check for a sum of 1 to after the nested for loop.

That'd look something more like:

```
  public static boolean isMarkovMatrix(double[][] m){
    double sum;

    for(int column = 0; column < m.length; column++){
      sum = 0;        
      for(int row = 0; row < m.length; row++){          
          sum += m[row][column];
          if (m[row][column] < 0){
              return false;
          }
      }
      if (sum != 1.0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: wowza, such a simple change, but it totally worked, and makes complete sense! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> *"... it continues to tell me that it's NOT a positive M.M ..."*

I cannot decipher the logic for the *isMarkovMatrix* method.

Here is a reference; not the solution.

```java
double e = 0;
for (int c = 0, m = a[0].length; c < m; c++, e = 0) {
    for (double[] r : a) e += r[c];
    if (e != 1) return false;
}
return true;
```

The problem here is you'll encounter precision errors when adding the *floating-point* values.

Use the *[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)* class instead.

```java
BigDecimal e = BigDecimal.ZERO;
for (int c = 0, n = m[0].length; c < n; c++, e = BigDecimal.ZERO) {
    for (double[] r : m)
        e = e.add(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(r[c])));
    if (e.compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) != 0) return false;
}
return true;
```

Output

```
Enter a 3-by-3 matrix row by row: 
.1 .2 .3
.4 .5 .6
.5 .3 .1
It is a Markov Matrix.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Markov
{
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    double m[][];
    void main()
    {
    System.out.println("Enter order of matrix");
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    int b=0;
    while(!(n>=3&&n<=9))
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR the value is out of bound");
        System.out.println("Re-enter");
        int x=sc.nextInt();
        n=x;
    }
    m=new double[n][n];
    for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m.length;j++)
       {
           m[i][j]=sc.nextDouble();
           while(m[i][j]<0)
           {
               System.out.println("ERROR negative value entered");
               System.out.println("Re-enter");
               int x=sc.nextInt();
               m[i][j]=x;
           }
        }
    }
    int a=0;
    for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m.length;j++)
        {
           System.out.print(m[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for(int r=0;r<n;r++)
    {   double s1=0.0;double s2=0.0;
        for(int c=0;c<n;c++)
        {
            s1+=m[r][c];
            s2+=m[c][r];
        }
        if(s1!=1||s2!=1)
        a++;
    }
    if(a>0)
    System.out.println("It is not a doubly markov matrix");
    else
    System.out.println("It is a doubly markov number");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).